# Some pattern questions in Latex

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

1. I wish to write Arzéla-Ascoli's theorem in my Latex work, but the é did not show up in the final file.
   I input `Arzéla-Ascoli` then the output is `Arzla-Ascoli`
2. I want to use   `\begin{align } k &=P(x)-Q(x)\\ &=f(x)\\ &=x+y\end{align}` to align all those equations, but I want to get rid of  (1)(2)(3) in the right of the equations,how could I make that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Statements such as "did not work" are not exactly specific. *What* didn't work? Did you get error and or warning messages? If so, what did these messages say? About the second  item: Please replace `$\begin{eqnarray}` and `\end{eqnarray}$` with `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`, respectively. By the way, since you're showing just one equation, it's not easy to interpret what you mean by "align all those equations". Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your comment, I edit my question with more details. Could you check it again?

Comment: Please, show as MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem. We need to know, which document class you use, which font you use . For how to write equations see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics

Comment: Arzéla is wrong; the name is Arzelà.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding item #1: You haven't indicated which TeX distribution, which TeX engine, and which LaTeX document class you employ. Hence, it's not possible to provide a definitive diagnosis of what may be going on. Assuming you employ pdflatex to compile your document, I'd start with adding the instructions

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to the preamble.

In the longer run, I'd further recommend making sure that you're using an up to date TeX distribution.

Regarding item #2: To get an *unnumbered* display math environment, just add `*` to its name. E.g., instead of `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`, you should write `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}`. This "star-adding" method also works for other display math environments, such as `equation`, `gather`, and `multline`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! All my questions are done.

Comment: @Rita Is good, in this case: 1) green check the answer; 2) upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem can be easily solved independently on your TeX setup by typing

```
Arzel\`a-Ascoli
```

Please, note that “Arzéla” is not the correct spelling of the name, which is

> [Arzelà](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesare_Arzel%C3%A0)

with a *grave* accent on the “a”.

The second issue, which would be a different question, is solved by using

```
\begin{align*}
k &=P(x)-Q(x)\\
&=f(x)\\
&=x+y
\end{align*}
```

Beware of spaces: `{align }` is wrong anyway.